# (.SVG, .PNG) not loading in react component

Tags: javascript, django, reactjs, svg, jsx

I am trying to load SVG and PNG  images in my react app.

I am running a back end server on Django.

I always get this error when I try to load any Image.

> "GET /b5cde312e6d66e389b1ca2ccfc013da0.png HTTP/1.1" 404 2195

***webpack.config.js***

```
            {
                test: /\.(jpg|png|svg)$/,
                loader: 'url-loader',
                options: {
                  limit: 25000,
                },
            },
            {
                test: /\.(jpg|png|svg)$/,
                loader: 'file-loader',
                options: {
                  name: '[path][name].[hash].[ext]',
                },
            },
```

My component

```
import React from 'react';
import '../App.css';
import Nav from '../components/Nav';
import  Logo from '../logo512.png'; 

export default class Dev extends React.Component {
  render(){
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Nav />
      <header className="App-header">
        <div className="container">
         <img src={Logo}  alt="React Logo" />
        </div>
      </header>
    </div>
  )
  }
}
```

Comment: Looks like you're passing the contents of the image file to `src` but `src` is expecting a file path so it gets confused. See if `src={'../logo512.png'}` does the trick. Just an educated guess. I don't know django.

Comment: logo512.png not Found 404.
it says that when I typed the code you mentioned

Comment: Maybe a relative path problem? Should it be '../images/logo512.png' or something like that?

Comment: The path is correct but the path intellisence can't figure that it's there

Comment: Try commenting the first rule you show in the webpack example, letting only the one for imgs loading with file-loader.  And by the path '../logo512.png' webpack understands its a level up of the current file, so be sure that path is valid. 

As a side comment, for further work if you add many images in your project, probably is better to serve them with the backend, Django STATIC_FOLDER https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/ can help for that, so then you pass src a path to the images.

Comment: I deleted the 1st rule still no change.

Comment: Any chance you could provide a link to the project on github? Or is it not on github (or not a public repo)? It really feels like an incorrect path but I can't tell without knowing the project structure. Also seeing more of webpack.config.js would help.

Comment: @RockySims https://github.com/ahmedgaafer/GraduationProject